# Difference between Javascript & C# Image File array

Tags: javascript, c#, image

In C#, I read an image file into a base64 encoded string using:

```
var img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\xxx.jpg");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
var arr = ms.ToArray();
var b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
```

In javascript, I do this:

```
var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0], //C:\xxx.jpg
r = new FileReader();
r.onloadend = function (e) {

    console.log(btoa(e.target.result));

}
r.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

I'm getting different results.

Ultimately, I'm trying to read it in Javascript, POST that to an API, save in a database, and then retrieve & use later. If I use the C# code above, I can store the file and retrieve/display it fine. If I try the Javascript option, I don't get a valid image. So I'm trying to work out why they're different / where the problem is. Any pointers?

Comment: By not a valid image, do you mean it can't be read in, or there are just color problems?  I've noticed WinForms Image class stores them in the order BGRA, whereas most every other API I've used stores it as RGBA, so the red and blue colors are inverted during translation.

Comment: You are saving the image onto the stream using `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif`. Shouldn't you  use `ImageFormat.Jpeg` ?

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, your c# code is converting the image to a base64 string.  However your javascript appears to simply be reading the binary data without conversion to base64.

Comment: @SamAxe That's what the `btoa()` is doing.

Comment: Thanks @MatiasCicero!

Comment: @Sean Sometimes you need another pair of eyes to fix these bugs.